# Как присваивается куки к id

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin, cookie

Я сделал обработчик отправки сообщений, и мне осталось указать адрес отправителя который берется из массивы куки.
Подскажите правильно ли я присвоил куки к идентификатору:
$u_id=$_COOKIE['id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно, так это и делается.